# Stop goroutine waiting on bufio.NewScanner

Tags: go, timeout, goroutine

Firstly I want to define my use of 'persistent', in case my usage is incorrect. It's a goroutine (called c()) that's started at startup and is maintained indefinitely, and there's only 1 instance.

My goroutine c() maintains a TCP connection and is used to send/receive data to a TCP server. Everything is fine until I implement the caller's timers - the goroutine c() continues to wait for bufio.NewScanner and writes a reply that's no longer needed back to the reply channel. The callers in this example are the 2 anonymous goroutines in the main function.

My problems are:

- preventing a caller from writing to the channel if TCP connection is down (since caller will not want to wait as long as it may take to re-connect to the TCP server)
- prevent TCP client goroutine c() from writing reply back to channel if caller's timer has expired. Alternatively, implement the timer in the goroutine c() and write some error message back to the channel then discard, or stop waiting for, the eventual reply from bufio.NewScanner is another option? Because Scan() is blocking I'm not sure how to implement this, after a few failed attempts
- if I implement the timer only in the goroutine c() then in the case of TCP server down for some minutes the callers will continue to send requests to the channel unaware of any TCP connection issues, continually building up the channel, which would be undesirable. Perhaps it's best to implement the timer in the anonymous goroutines (to catch TCP connection problems), but still have goroutine c() equally aware of the timer (to catch delayed server responses), and respond within this timer limit, either with the contents of scanner.Text() or some error message?

The way I'm validating the request/reply/channel messages correspond is by comparing the int value. If I remove the timers from the callers they all sync up so I believe it is working fine until I re-implement timers (select statement in the anonymous goroutines)

Simulated TCP server

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "net"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

//main ...
func main() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":8013")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Listening on port 8013")
        for {
            conn, cerr := ln.Accept()
            if cerr != nil {
                fmt.Println("Some connection error: " + err.Error() + "\r\n")
            } else {
                go handleConnection(conn)
            }
        }
    }
}

func handleConnection(conn net.Conn) {
    remoteAddr := conn.RemoteAddr().String()
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(conn)
    for {
        ok := scanner.Scan()
        if !ok {
            break
        }
        fmt.Println("handleConnection received " + scanner.Text())
        n := rand.Intn(1000 - 0)
        //simulate a delay in processing the request by sleeping for some random time
        time.Sleep(time.Duration(n) * time.Millisecond)
        fmt.Println("sleeping " + strconv.Itoa(n) + "ms for " + scanner.Text())
        conn.SetWriteDeadline(time.Now().Add(1 * time.Second))
        _, err := conn.Write([]byte("OK:" + scanner.Text() + "\r\n"))
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error writing to stream")
        } else {
            fmt.Println("Replying to " + scanner.Text() + ".")
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("Client at " + remoteAddr + " disconnected.\r\n")
}
```

TCP client

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

const (
    timerExpiry int64 = 500
)

var (
    conn        net.Conn
    err         error
    cerr        error
    comms       chan S
    c2          chan string
    deadTCPConn bool
)

//S is a struct
type S struct {
    msg int
    ch  chan string
    t   time.Time
}

//main ...
func main() {
    deadTCPConn = false
    fmt.Println("launching...")
    comms = make(chan S, 100)
    c2 = make(chan string, 100)
    go c()
    go func() {
        var ch1 = make(chan string, 100)
        for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
            s1 := S{i, ch1, time.Now()}
            if !deadTCPConn {
                comms <- s1
                //fmt.Println(<-ch1) //uncomment this and responses will all be in order
                //use the below select statement and responses are given for the wrong caller 'i', as bufio scanner still waits for response even after timeout
                select {
                case x := <-ch1:
                    fmt.Println(x + " for caller " + strconv.Itoa(i))
                case <-time.After(time.Duration(timerExpiry) * time.Millisecond):
                    fmt.Println("Response too slow for " + strconv.Itoa(i))
                }
            } else {
                fmt.Println("Dead TCP Connection detected. Abandoning msg: " + strconv.Itoa(i))
                time.Sleep(250 * time.Millisecond) //arbitrary wait time to introduce a small delay between simulated caller requests
            }
        }
    }()
    go func() {
        var ch2 = make(chan string, 100)
        for i := 100; i < 200; i++ {
            var s2 = S{i, ch2, time.Now()}
            comms <- s2
            //fmt.Println(<-ch2) //uncomment this and responses will all be in order
            //use the below select statement and responses are given for the wrong caller 'i', as bufio scanner still waits for response even after timeout
            select {
            case x := <-ch2:
                fmt.Println(x + " for caller " + strconv.Itoa(i))
            case <-time.After(time.Duration(timerExpiry) * time.Millisecond):
                fmt.Println("Response too slow for " + strconv.Itoa(i))
            }
        }
    }()
    time.Sleep(100 * time.Second)
}

func c() {
    conn, err = net.Dial("tcp", "192.168.68.102:8013")
    for {
        select {
        case i := <-comms:
            fmt.Println("Attempting send MSG#" + strconv.Itoa(i.msg))
        Reconnect:
            if err != nil || cerr != nil {
                //reconnect
                deadTCPConn = true
                if cerr != nil {
                    //if we got here because of error writing to stream, reset the cerr variable to nil
                    cerr = nil
                }
                fmt.Println("Connection error, attempting reconnect")
                conn, err = net.Dial("tcp", "192.168.68.102:8013")
                for {
                    if err != nil {
                        time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
                        fmt.Println("Connection dead, trying again")
                        conn, err = net.Dial("tcp", "192.168.68.102:8013")
                    } else {
                        deadTCPConn = false
                        goto SendMsg
                    }
                }
            }
        SendMsg:
            //conn is assumed good, try to send message
            if (time.Now().Sub(i.t).Milliseconds()) < timerExpiry {
                conn.SetWriteDeadline(time.Now().Add(1 * time.Second))
                _, cerr = conn.Write([]byte("MSG #" + strconv.Itoa(i.msg) + "\r\n"))
                if cerr != nil {
                    fmt.Println("Error writing to stream")
                    goto Reconnect
                } else {
                    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(conn)
                    for {
                        ok := scanner.Scan()
                        if !ok {
                            break
                        }
                        if len(scanner.Text()) > 0 {
                            fmt.Println("Waited " + strconv.FormatInt(time.Now().Sub(i.t).Milliseconds(), 10) + " for " + scanner.Text())
                            if (time.Now().Sub(i.t).Milliseconds()) > timerExpiry {
                                //assume the caller has given up on this one
                                //don't write to channel
                                fmt.Println("waited too long in Scanner for " + strconv.Itoa(i.msg) + "...")
                                break
                            } else {
                                i.ch <- "----CH Received: " + scanner.Text() + " for " + strconv.Itoa(i.msg)
                                break
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Update:
I appear to have found progress. TCP Client code above is updated to include:

- new const timerExpiry, global variable deadTCPConn to track TCP connection
- extend the S struct to include a timestamp, which marks when the anonymous goroutine wrote to the channel
- first anonymous goroutine has included the update to check deadTCPConn and not write to channel if true. Second anonymous goroutine left as is for comparison
- in TCP Client goroutine if TCP connection err != nil, mark deadTCPConn = true until we can reestablish connection with the server, then set back to false
- before we send any message, compare the difference between caller's timestamp in the channel struct with time.Now() to decide if we write back to the channel. If timerExpiry has passed we know the caller has abandoned the request and processed it accordingly. This logic accounts for the message that was read from the channel when the goroutine first observed a TCP server disconnection and re-established the connection
- We compare timestamps when Scan() returns output from TCP server, assess the total delay and compare with timerExpiry to know if the caller would have abandoned by now or if it's OK to write back to the return channel

I can stop the TCP Server, observe the caller's abandoning requests or hitting timerExpiry, then successfully receiving responses when TCP Server is started again. There's likely some edge scenarios I haven't encountered in such simple testing.

Comment: "It's a goroutine (called c())" -- No, your goroutine is not called `c()`, goroutines don't have any identity or name.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand your question, but it sounds like you're trying to maintain synchronous communication using a single managing goroutine. This is incredibly hard, as you're discovering. I think a redesign is in order.

Comment: Close the network connection to cause the scanner to return with an error. What is the higher-level problem you are trying to solve?  Is it that you are creating a client for a request response protocol? Does the protocol support pipelining?

Comment: @Flimzy thanks for the correction on my phrasing. I need to work on how I describe my code more. And yes you did understand correctly. I think I have a solution, and will update OP with details.

Comment: @Muffin Top, there's no pipelining here, just request/response and handling the output. The higher level issue is that this request/response is used with a web interface where I want to control the maximum information retrieval time for consistent user experience. That's the primary motivation

Comment: Write requests and read responses in a loop. The application must read the response to continue using the connection, even when higher-level code abandons the transaction.  Ensure that the response channel has sufficient capacity that loop does not block on an abandoned transaction.

Comment: It sounds like one goroutine per request would work perfectly. And this is the default model in a web server, so you may not need to do any of that yourself.